# displaying ant task/target in recorder log

Tags: ant

I am using the ant task `<record>` to create a log file of the output and activity of my ant build script. The problem is:

> i am not seeing the names of the `targets` that are being executed.

For instance: When my target called `cleanFW` is being executed, i only see the stuff being done inside the target and NOT the name of the target it self. Since this is happening, i have no way of telling when `cleanFW` began in the log file.

Is there a way to get this `cleanFW` target name to appear? It was appearing when i was using the flag `-logfile`. But i had to switch to `<record>` because i want to record log file and see the output in console.

**Using Ant 1.8.2**

---

**simple solution**

My simple solution to this is to just put an echo in each one of the targets. Just wondering if there was a better way.

---

**sample code where it is not working**

```
<project name="foobar">

<record name="test.txt" action="start" append="true" loglevel="verbose" />

... lots of property stuff here ...

    <target name="cleanFW">
        <record name="test.txtaction="start" append="true" loglevel="verbose"/>
        <mkdir dir="${FOOBAR_OUTPUT}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${FOOBAR_GEN}"/>
        <delete includeemptydirs="true"> 
            <fileset dir="${FOOBAR_BIN}" includes="**/*"/>
            <fileset dir="${FOOBAR_GENERATED}" includes="**/*"/>
            <fileset dir="${FOOBAR_NODES}" includes="**/*"/>
            <fileset dir="${FOOBAR_GEN}" includes="**/*"/>
        </delete>
        <mkdir dir="${FOOBAR_OUTPUT}"/>
        <record name="test.txt" action="stop"/>
    </target>

<record name="test.txt" action="stop"/>   

</project>
```

The reason why i have the first `record name="test.txt" action="start" append="true" loglevel="verbose" />` at the top, is because i want all of the statements and stuff that are before the targets to be displayed too. Like my property sets and all that jazz. I left that junk out because it is not important.

Comment: It works for me with a really simple buildfile using Ant 1.8.2.  Can you create a potted example that shows it not working?  Also, which Ant version are you using?  I think there were some reports of recorder-related issues with the antcall task a while ago.

Comment: @martinclayton: i am using ant 1.8.2 and i posted example code snippet above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm at a bit of a loss to explain *why* exactly, but I think you need to omit the last `record` 'stop' task - the one that is outside of a target.

Having said that, you can probably omit all of the `record` tasks except the first 'start', and get the result you want.

Comment: So, i should not even put a `stop` in the build file?

Comment: That worked for me.  I think you need only 'stop' if you want to record only part of your build process.  It looks like you're closing the recorder twice at the moment - but I'm not sure why that has the effect it does.